# Filter words of a collection by characters typed in text box and show the resulting words in a listbox

Tags: c#, dictionary, listbox

I am developing a dictionary and I have around 110,000 words. At the windows_load I load all the words in a sorted dictionary. Then when a user start typing characters in the text box my program should search the sorted dictionary and shows the words starting with those characters in the listbox.

For example when user enters "com" in the text box I want the program to show all words starting with "com" in the listbox

I am wondering if I am using the correct data structure but it searches according to the key stored in it.

```
namespace StringDictionaryClass
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedDic = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadWords();
    }
    private void LoadWords()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string word;
        // Read the file and display it word by word.
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        if (File.Exists(path + "\\Words.txt"))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path + "\\Words.txt");
            while ((word = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sortedDic.Add(word, "");
                counter++;
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    private void earchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string key = searchBox.Text;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> dictionaryEntry in sortedDic)
        {
            if (key == dictionaryEntry.Key)
            {
                listBoxWords1.Items.Add(dictionaryEntry.Key);
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking if the entire search string matches a key in the dictionary, where you actually only wanted to find words that start with the search text.

You can do the following in your searchBox_TextChanged handler ising linq.

```
// Get the words in the dictionary starting with the textbox text.
var matching = sortedDic.Keys.Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchText.Text)).ToList();


// Assign the values to the listbox.
listboxWords1.Items.AddRange(matching);
```

Comment: the problem with this peace code is that adds hundreds of words to the listbox by entering or deleting every character. It works very slow and consumes lots of memory and CPU. Any improvement please?

Comment: Well you have this running every single time text has changed in the text box. Maybe running this in a separate thread or on a timer when the user pauses in the textbox is what you want.

Comment: Yes exactly. The problem is this that if I type 'A' it finds all the words starting with 'A' and all of them inserted in the var matching. Then when I type 'p' it also inserts all words starting with 'ap' and so on. Then all of them added to listBox.

Comment: My solution to the problem is that when I type 'A' it should find  words starting with 'A' but only first 20 of them should be added to var matching. Means the size of var matching should be fixed to 20. then when I type 'p' 20 words starting with 'Ap' should be found and these 20 words should be replaced in the listBox with 20 words that were added previously. 
I don't know how to do it